# How can i generate html in action from partial view?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some action. I want send mail. usually i doing this way.

```
public ActionResult Action(Model model)
{
    string body = 
             "<html>"+
             "<head>"+
             "</head>"+
             "<body>"+
             "</body>"+
             "</html>"

    MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    Message.Subject = "some subject";
    Message.Body = body;
    Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(adres));
    Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient();
    Smtp.EnableSsl = false; 
    Smtp.Send(Message);

    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction","Controller");
}
```

Can any say how can i generate HTML from PartialView and send this html trough email?

something like this

```
public ActionResult Action(Model model)
{    
    string str = GetHtmlFromPartialView("NamePartialView",model);


    MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    Message.Subject = "some subject";
    Message.Body = str;
    Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(adres));
    Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient();
    Smtp.EnableSsl = false; 
    Smtp.Send(Message);

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MvcMailer package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). Scott Hanselman also [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx) about it. You will see how much easier and fun is to send emails with it. The mail templates are defined as Razor views.